# Vknet api двойная аутентификация

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, vknet

Пользуюсь в проекте [таким](https://vknet.github.io/vk/) API для VK. 
При авторизации vk, если пользователь пользуется двухэтапной аутентификация, нужно вводить код (ваш к.о.). 
Возникла примерно следующая проблема:      
не знаю как определить (какой *exception* словить?), что пользователю нужно дополнительное поле для кода из SMS. 

 
Т.е. если для капчи есть отдельный тип *exception'a* (CaptchaNeededException), то для ошибки такой аутентификации я ошибки не нашел.

**Вопрос**:

Как узнать, что пользователь пользуется двойной аутентификацией **до** или **после** введения логина и пароля? Есть ли такая возможность в этой API?

 
API то достаточно широко используется в кругах программистов C#, но найти ответ на этот вопрос я как-то не смог =\

Код, в котором происходит логин:

```
private async void login()
    {         
        try
        {
            Authorization.IsLoginButtonEnable = false;
            var vk = new VkNet.VkApi();
            if (Authorization.IsCaptchaNeeded)
            {
                await vk.AuthorizeAsync(new VkNet.ApiAuthParams
                {
                    ApplicationId = Authorization.AppID,
                    Login = Authorization.Email,
                    Password = Authorization.Password,
                    Settings = Authorization.Settings,
                    CaptchaSid = Authorization.CaptchaSid,
                    CaptchaKey = Authorization.Captcha,
                    TwoFactorAuthorization = () =>
                    {
                        Console.Write("Please enter code: ");
                        string value = Console.ReadLine();

                        return value;
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                await vk.AuthorizeAsync(new VkNet.ApiAuthParams
                {
                    ApplicationId = Authorization.AppID,
                    Login = Authorization.Email,
                    Password = Authorization.Password,
                    Settings = Authorization.Settings,
                    TwoFactorAuthorization = () =>
                    {
                        Console.Write("Please enter code: ");
                        string value = Console.ReadLine();

                        return value;
                    }
                });
            }
            VkNet.Model.User user = new VkNet.Model.User();                
        }
        catch (VkNet.Exception.CaptchaNeededException cEx)
        {
            Authorization.IsLoginButtonEnable = true;
            Authorization.IsCaptchaEnable = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            Authorization.CaptchaImgUri = cEx.Img.AbsoluteUri;
            Authorization.CaptchaSid = cEx.Sid;
            Authorization.IsCaptchaNeeded = true;
        }
        catch (VkNet.Exception.VkApiAuthorizationException eAx)
        {
            Authorization.IsLoginButtonEnable = true;
            Authorization.IsAuthSuccess = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Неверное имя пользователя или пароль! Попробуйте еще раз!", "Error");
        }            
    }
```

UPD. 
Проблема с определением отпала. 
Ответом на этот вопрос было следующее:

 В методе авторизации этого API в @ApiAuthParams есть обобщенный делегат

```
Func<string>
```

, который отвечает за двухфакторную авторизацию. По задумке авторов, он должен срабатывать только тогда, когда эта самая авторизация нужна. 
Но! Он срабатывает постоянно, с любыми значениями, не давая возможности войти вообще. Может кто знает, что с этим делать теперь?)

Код с авторизацией обновил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ответ на мою [Issue](https://github.com/vknet/vk/issues/336) на github'е проекта дали такой ответ, в общем то это костыль, но работающий:

```
public bool AuthUsing2FA { get; set; } = false;

[JsonIgnore]
public Func<string> Auth2Fa { get; set; }

// ...

TwoFactorAuthorization = (this.AuthUsing2FA) ? Auth2Fa : default(Func<string>)
```

Answer (score 1):

Красиво решение этой проблемы не нашел нигде, в т.ч. и у разрабов (пока что). 
Создал [Issue](https://github.com/vknet/vk/issues/336) для этой проблемы в github'e библиотеки, ответа пока что нету.
Для себя решил проблему пока что так:

1) При авторизации сразу спрашиваем у пользователя установлена ли у него двойна аутентификация?; 
2) Если нет - авторизируемся без нее; Если включена - авторизируемся с ней (пользователь, у которого она не включена - не войдет); 
3) Профит.

В коде это выглядит примерно так:
**C#:**

```
private async void login()
    {
        Func<string> security = () =>
        {
            try
            {    
                Authorization.TwoFactorNextView = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                Authorization.TwoFactorView = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Authorization.SecurityCode)) ;
                return Authorization.SecurityCode;
            }
            finally
            {
                Authorization.TwoFactorNextView = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                Authorization.TwoFactorView = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
                Authorization.IsAuthSuccess = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
        };

        try
        {                
            Authorization.IsLoginButtonEnable = false;
            var vk = new VkNet.VkApi();
            if (Authorization.IsTwoFactorAuth)
            {
                if (Authorization.IsCaptchaNeeded)
                {
                    await vk.AuthorizeAsync(new VkNet.ApiAuthParams
                    {
                        ApplicationId = Authorization.AppID,
                        Login = Authorization.Email,
                        Password = Authorization.Password,
                        Settings = Authorization.Settings,
                        CaptchaSid = Authorization.CaptchaSid,
                        CaptchaKey = Authorization.Captcha,
                        TwoFactorAuthorization = security
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    await vk.AuthorizeAsync(new VkNet.ApiAuthParams
                    {
                        ApplicationId = Authorization.AppID,
                        Login = Authorization.Email,
                        Password = Authorization.Password,
                        Settings = Authorization.Settings,
                        //TwoFactorAuthorization = security
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Authorization.IsCaptchaNeeded)
                {
                    await vk.AuthorizeAsync(new VkNet.ApiAuthParams
                    {
                        ApplicationId = Authorization.AppID,
                        Login = Authorization.Email,
                        Password = Authorization.Password,
                        Settings = Authorization.Settings,
                        CaptchaSid = Authorization.CaptchaSid,
                        CaptchaKey = Authorization.Captcha,
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    await vk.AuthorizeAsync(new VkNet.ApiAuthParams
                    {
                        ApplicationId = Authorization.AppID,
                        Login = Authorization.Email,
                        Password = Authorization.Password,
                        Settings = Authorization.Settings,
                    });
                }
            }
            VkNet.Model.User user = new VkNet.Model.User();

            addToPlaylist(user, vk);
        }
        catch (VkNet.Exception.CaptchaNeededException cEx)
        {
            Authorization.IsLoginButtonEnable = true;
            Authorization.IsCaptchaEnable = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            Authorization.CaptchaImgUri = cEx.Img.AbsoluteUri;
            Authorization.CaptchaSid = cEx.Sid;
            Authorization.IsCaptchaNeeded = true;
        }
        catch (VkNet.Exception.VkApiAuthorizationException eAx)
        {
            Authorization.IsLoginButtonEnable = true;
            Authorization.IsAuthSuccess = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Неверное имя пользователя или пароль! Попробуйте еще раз!", "Error");
        }
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window
x:Class="MP3_Player.View.AuthorizationView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:MP3_Player.Helpers"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MP3_Player.View"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MP3_Player.ViewModel"
Title="Авторизация Vkontakte"
Width="400"
Height="300"
Closing="Window_Closing"
ResizeMode="NoResize"
Visibility="{Binding Path=Authorization.Auth_visible}"
WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:AuthorizationViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding Authorization.TwoFactorNextView}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox
                Margin="87,0,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Content="Двухэтапная аутентификация?"
                IsChecked="{Binding Path=Authorization.IsTwoFactorAuth}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row="5"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            FontFamily="Yu Gothic UI Semibold"
            FontSize="11"
            Foreground="#FFA01414"
            Text="Неверное имя пользователя или пароль! Попробуйте еще раз!"
            Visibility="{Binding Path=Authorization.IsAuthSuccess}" />
        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Width="200" Source="{Binding Path=Authorization.CaptchaImgUri}" />
            <StackPanel
                Width="194"
                Orientation="Vertical"
                Visibility="{Binding Path=Authorization.IsCaptchaEnable}">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Введите текст с картинки" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Authorization.Captcha, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <StackPanel
                Margin="20,0,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="0,5,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="14"
                    Foreground="Blue"
                    Text="Вход в систему" />
                <Line
                    Margin="5"
                    Stroke="Blue"
                    StrokeThickness="0.1"
                    X1="-10"
                    X2="360">
                    <Line.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect />
                    </Line.Effect>
                </Line>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel
                Margin="20,0,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Приложение " />
                <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" Text="MP3 Player " />
                <TextBlock Text="запрашивает доступ к вашему аккаунту" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="E-mail или телефон:" />
        <TextBox
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="5"
            Text="{Binding Path=Authorization.Email}" />
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="Введите пароль:" />
        <PasswordBox
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="5"
            PasswordChar="*">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <custom:PasswordBehavior Password="{Binding Path=Authorization.Password, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </PasswordBox>
        <Button
            Grid.Row="6"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="5,5,100,5"
            Background="#6084A9"
            Command="{Binding Path=LoginCommand}"
            Content="Войти"
            FontFamily="Arial"
            FontSize="11"
            FontWeight="ExtraBold"
            Foreground="White"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Authorization.IsLoginButtonEnable}" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="6"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="100,5,5,5"
            Background="#6084A9"
            Click="Button_Click"
            Content="Отмена"
            FontFamily="Arial"
            FontSize="11"
            FontWeight="ExtraBold"
            Foreground="White" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding Authorization.TwoFactorView}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="Введите код из SMS:" />
        <TextBox
            Grid.Row="1"
            Height="40"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding Path=Authorization.SecurityCode, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Button
            Grid.Row="2"
            Command="{Binding Path=KeyPressedCommand}"
            Content="Подтвердить" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[Ссылка](https://github.com/alexandrmazur96/MP3_Player) на этот проект на github'е. 
Если кто знает решение этого вопроса более изящным способом (с использованием этой библиотеки), буду рад увидеть.